# CSS3 and HTML5 Navigation error

Tags: html, css, web

This is the current issue im tackling, as you can see the navigation is completely haywire. Each link except the home has an extra empty box to the left of the normal link. take a look in my code and see if any has a quick fix? (cant post picture yet but I have one if you would like to see)

html5:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>ChonBonStudios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">

        <!-- Including the Lobster font from Google's Font Directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />

        <!-- Enabling HTML5 support for Internet Explorer -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Website">
            <header>
                <div id="Logo">
                    <a href="ChonBonStudios-Home.html"><img id="Company"   src="ChonBonStudios Logo.png"></a>
                </div>
            </header>

            <ul class="fancyNav">
                <li id="home"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Home.html" class="homeIcon" >Home</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="ChonBonStudios-About.html"><li>About</a></li>
                <li id="android"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Android.html"><li>Android Products</a></li>
                <li id="apple"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Apple.html"><li>Apple Products</a></li>
                <li id="computer"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Computer.html"><li>Computer Services</a></li>
                <li id="youtube"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Youtube.html"><li>Youtube</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Contact.html"><li>Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <section>
            </section>

            <aside>
            </aside>
        </div>

        <div id="MainFooter">
            <footer>
                Copyright Austin Choncek 2013
            </footer>
        </div>

    </body>
</html> 

css3:
    body{
        background-color: #625D5D;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: Comic Sans MS;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #1cf1cb;
    }

    #Website{
        background-color: #fd4c1d;
        width: 1000px;
        border: #1a1a1a solid 2px;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: none;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    }

    #Logo{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 0px;
        border: none;
        width: 690px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .fancyNav{
        /* Affects the UL element */
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .fancyNav li{
        /* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */

        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,from(#fefefe), color-stop(0.5,#f0f0f0), color-stop(0.51, #e6e6e6));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe 0%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e6e6e6 51%);

        border-right: 1px solid rgba(9, 9, 9, 0.125);

        /* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */

        box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset;

        position:relative;

        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .fancyNav li:after{

        /* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */ 

        content:'.';
        text-indent:-9999px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:1;
        opacity:0;

        /* Gradients! */

        background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));
        background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        background-image:linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));

        /* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */

        box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

        /* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */

        -moz-transition:0.25s all;
        -webkit-transition:0.25s all;
        -o-transition:0.25s all;
        transition:0.25s all;
    }
    /* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */

    .fancyNav li:first-child{
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }

    .fancyNav li:first-child:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
        box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;

        border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
    }

    .fancyNav li:last-child{
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    }

    /* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */

    .fancyNav li:last-child:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after{
        box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;

        border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;
    }

    .fancyNav li:hover:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:after,
    .fancyNav li:target:after{
        /* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
        opacity:1;
    }

    .fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
    .fancyNav:hover li:target:after{
        /* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
        opacity:0;
    }

    .fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
    .fancyNav li:target:hover:after{
        opacity:1 !important;
    }

     /* Styling the anchor elements */

    .fancyNav li a{
        color: #5d5d5d;
        display: inline-block;
        font: 20px/1 Lobster,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 12px 35px 14px;
        position: relative;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        z-index:2;
        text-decoration:none !important;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    .fancyNav a.homeIcon{
        background:url('home.png') no-repeat center center;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        width: 16px;
    }

    #MainFooter{
        background-color: #1a1a1a;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        padding:20px;
        border-top: 2px solid white;
        width: 1000px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 496px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra random `<li>` tags in the `<a>` tags, try:

```
<ul class="fancyNav">
        <li id="home"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Home.html" class="homeIcon" >Home</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="ChonBonStudios-About.html">About</a></li>
        <li id="android"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Android.html">Android Products</a></li>
        <li id="apple"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Apple.html">Apple Products</a></li>
        <li id="computer"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Computer.html">Computer Services</a></li>
        <li id="youtube"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Youtube.html">Youtube</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="ChonBonStudios-Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Yes i just noticed that one i went into developer tools in chrome and looking i found the extra tags, thanks for the answer, i was about to close this question!